# My minGW\bin file cannot be parsed - how can I fix it?

Tags: c++, c

```
[9/30/2023, 3:58:27 PM] "C:\MinGW\bin" could not be parsed. 'includePath' from c_cpp_properties.json in folder 'BOOMING BULLS' will be used instead.
[9/30/2023, 3:58:28 PM] For C++ source files, IntelliSenseMode was changed from "windows-msvc-x64" to "windows-gcc-x86" based on compiler args and querying compilerPath: "C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe"
[9/30/2023, 3:58:28 PM] IntelliSenseMode was changed because it didn't match the detected compiler.  Consider setting "compilerPath" instead.  Set "compilerPath" to "" to disable detection of system includes and defines.
[9/30/2023, 3:58:28 PM] For C source files, IntelliSenseMode was changed from "windows-msvc-x64" to "windows-gcc-x86" and cStandard was changed from "gnu17" to "gnu11" based on compiler args and querying compilerPath: "C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe"
[9/30/2023, 3:58:28 PM] IntelliSenseMode was changed because it didn't match the detected compiler.  Consider setting "compilerPath" instead.  Set "compilerPath" to "" to disable detection of system includes and defines.
[9/30/2023, 3:58:28 PM] "C:\MinGW\bin" could not be parsed. 'includePath' from c_cpp_properties.json in folder 'ARRAYS' will be used instead.
[9/30/2023, 3:58:29 PM] "C:\MinGW\bin" could not be parsed. 'includePath' from c_cpp_properties.json in folder 'ARRAYS' will be used instead.
[9/30/2023, 3:58:39 PM] "C:\MinGW\bin" could not be parsed. 'includePath' from c_cpp_properties.json in folder 'ARRAYS' will be used instead.
[9/30/2023, 3:58:40 PM] "C:\MinGW\bin" could not be parsed. 'includePath' from c_cpp_properties.json in folder 'ARRAYS' will be used instead.
```

my c/c++ programs was working well before then i installed anaconda navigator to work on my python project for that i changed my VSC interpreter to conda after completing my project i uninstalled anaconda navigator and return back to c++. since then, Whenever i open my VScode   these errors are popped in terminal.(all required extensions are already downloaded)

Comment: Where do you get these errors from? What are you trying to do? What environment (editor etc.) are you using? What commands are you running? What does your configuration look like? Please [edit] your question to give us more details.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. And please also read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You misconfigured VSC somehow. You need to tell us what exactly you did, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: One thing is you did not follow the official VSCode MinGW tutorial: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)  This tutorial tells you to install msys2 and have that install MinGW. I recommend you remove your current MinGW and follow the official guide.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems while you uninstalled the anaconda it also messed up some files and folders from MinGW

Try reinstalling MinGW and Set VSC default interpreter then it should work again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).